# remote control laser meter

Tags: laser

I am looking to buy a laser distance meter and to connect it to a motor and a 3g cellular to control both the motor and to mesure the distance. I will appriciate your advice on how to do so. thanks

Comment: What kind of distances are you interested in measuring?

Comment: shold be around 50-70 meters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a single beam distance measurement.  There are lots of devices like the [Bosch laser distance meter](http://www.boschtools.com/products/tools/Pages/BoschProductDetail.aspx?pid=DLR130K).  But i don't think they have the range you want, and also probably no computer interface.

SICK makes a 2D laser scanner that used to be standard in robotics.  (You can see many of these mounted atop the DARPA Grand Challenge cars for example).  I think the standard used to be the LMS200 series, but it looks that has been replaced by the [LMS500 series](https://www.mysick.com/eCat.aspx?go=FinderSearch&Cat=Row&At=Fa&Cult=English&FamilyID=344&Category=Produktfinder&Selections=50696,34243).  These work outdoors, have ranges up to 80 meters, and are easily interfaced with a computer.

Comment: thanks. yet, bosch products have no details about pc connectivity except to the ones with blooetooth